# ImapResponseException Duplicate folder INBOX

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email, exchange-server, imap

I am working on a c# application using [mail.dll](http://www.limilabs.com/mail) from limilabs. Using the folowing code I am retrieving mail from the server.

```
     try
            {
                imap.ServerCertificateValidate += new ServerCertificateValidateEventHandler(Validate);
                imap.Connect(server);
                Console.WriteLine("Imap Connected");
                imap.UseBestLogin(username, password);
                Console.WriteLine("Imap Logged in");
                string[] folders = new string[] { "Verwijderde items", "INBOX"};
                foreach (string folder in folders)
                {
                    if (folder.Equals(string.Empty))
                        break;

                    foreach (FolderInfo folderInfo in imap.GetFolders())
                    {
                        if (folderInfo.Name.Equals(folder))
                        {
                            imap.Select(folder); //ImapResponseException

                            //Process found mail

                            break;
                        }
                    }                        
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Imap not Connected");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
```

`"verwijderde items"` is dutch for removed items or recycle bin.

`ImapResponseException: Duplicate folder INBOX were detected in the mailbox. Therefore the user's connection was disconnected.`

This exception is throw because the username and password I use to login has access to the inboxes off all employees. Maybe I need to use `imap.Select("mail@adres.com/inbox/ + folder")` to specify which use I want to access. But I do not know the file structure imap uses. Maybe this isn't the solution with this specific dll. All ideas are welcome.

The server I am connecting to is Windows Server 2008 R2 with Microsoft Exchange 2007.

Update 1:
Mail.dll documentation: http://www.limilabs.com/static/mail/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you are calling `imap.Select(folder);` when what you should probably be doing is calling the `Select()` method on the `folderInfo` or perhaps a `folderInfo.Path` string (I'm not sure what properties `folderInfo` has).

If you're willing to switch to a free/open source IMAP library, I'd suggest using my [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library instead.

To do what you are trying to do in MailKit, the code would look something like this:

```
try {
    using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
        client.Connect (server, 993, true); // I assume you are connecting via SSL
        client.Authenticate (username, password);

        string[] names = new string[] { "Verwijderde items", "INBOX" };

        // client.PersonalNamespaces are the mailboxes that belong to you
        foreach (var personalNamespace in client.PersonalNamespaces) {
            // get the root folder in your personal namespace
            // (there's always at least 1 personal namespace)
            var root = client.GetFolder (personalNamespace);

            // get the top-level folders in your personal namespace
            foreach (var folder in root.GetSubfolders ()) {
                foreach (var name in names) {
                    if (folder.Name == name) {
                        // Select the folder (if you want to change flags,
                        // use FolderAccess.ReadWrite)
                        folder.Open (FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

                        // process mail
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // client.SharedNamespaces are the shared mailboxes
        foreach (var sharedNamespace in client.SharedNamespaces) {
            var root = client.GetFolder (sharedNamespace);

            // get the top-level folders in your shared namespace
            foreach (var folder in root.GetSubfolders ()) {
                foreach (var name in names) {
                    if (folder.Name == name) {
                        // Select the folder (if you want to change flags,
                        // use FolderAccess.ReadWrite)
                        folder.Open (FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

                        // process mail
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Imap not Connected");
    Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine (ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Obviously you'd be able to simplify the above code because you could write a method that takes a `FolderNamespaceCollection` argument and just pass it the personal or shared namespaces, like this:

```
void ProcessMail (ImapClient client, FolderNamespaceCollection namespaces)
{
    string[] names = new string[] { "Verwijderde items", "INBOX" };

    // client.PersonalNamespaces are the mailboxes that belong to you
    foreach (var @namespace in namespaces) {
        // get the root folder in the namespace
        var root = client.GetFolder (@namespace);

        // get the top-level folders in the namespace
        foreach (var folder in root.GetSubfolders ()) {
            foreach (var name in names) {
                if (folder.Name == name) {
                    // Select the folder (if you want to change flags,
                    // use FolderAccess.ReadWrite)
                    folder.Open (FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

                    // process mail
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An even simpler approach, however, would be something like this since you already know the folder names you want:

```
void ProcessMail (ImapClient client, FolderNamespaceCollection namespaces)
{
    string[] names = new string[] { "Verwijderde items", "INBOX" };

    foreach (var @namespace in namespaces) {
        // get the root folder in the namespace
        var root = client.GetFolder (@namespace);

        // get specific folders:
        foreach (var name in names) {
            try {
                var folder = root.GetSubfolder (name);

                // Select the folder (if you want to change flags,
                // use FolderAccess.ReadWrite)
                folder.Open (FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

                // process mail
            } catch (FolderNotFoundException) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Imap.select(folderinfo) does indeed exist but gives the same exception. Documentation can be found here: http://www.limilabs.com/static/mail/documentation/

Comment: Looks like my assumption about what folderInfo.Name represented was wrong. I guess it's the full path based on those docs, but I had assumed it was the mailbox name w/o the folder path. I've updated my answer to show how to do what you want to do using my own IMAP library in case you are interested.